# nginx - disable access via IP

Tags: nginx

I want to redirect to 444 when someone uses the IP address. Most online says to use the underscore to catch all but I currently have a block that uses that to redirect http to https:

```
    listen      80;
    listen      443 ssl;
    server_name _;
    ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/nginx.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/nginx.key;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}
```

What's the best way to include both without having to use a If statement?

Comment: There are two ways to go about this, it can be specified in a `server` block (what you've given), or you can use a `location` directive.

Comment: The underscore is deprecated and effectively does nothing. You are looking for `default_server` on the `listen` directive. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html#miscellaneous_names).

Answer (score 1):

Why not use the solution with an if-statement?

```
    if ($http_host != "example.com") {
        return 444;
    }
```